# Is it any way I could obtain the current value of top from the animation fuction given below

Tags: jquery, css, animation

```
$(".box").animate({
    top: '400px',
    height: '45px',
    width: '200px',},7000).fadeOut("slow").hide("slow");
```

Comment: what do you mean the `top` from the `animation` ? you want to retrieve the top value of the `box` after the animation finished ?

Comment: Yes, This is part of a small typing game which I am working on right now, Words will be randomly generated and move down continuously, when the generated word matches with the word on the text box the box will hide, the remaining words will go down and  fadeout, I wants to retrieve the top value when the animation is finished and use that value to reduce the game life of the player. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ask for it at any time during the animation via [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
var top = $(".box").css("top");   // `top` will be a string, like 18.28px
```

...or via [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)'s `top`:

```
var top = $(".box").offset().top; // `top` will be a number
```

Example:

```js
var box = $(".box");
box.animate({
    top: '400px',
    height: '45px',
    width: '200px',},7000).fadeOut("slow").hide("slow");

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var top = box.css("top");
  var pos = box.offset();
  console.log('.css("top"): ' + top);
  console.log('.offset().top: ' + pos.top);
  if (Math.round(parseFloat(top)) >= 400) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 7010);
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">x</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that in both cases, you'll get the value for the *first* element matching `.box`. If you have several of them that you're animating all at once, you'll need an `each` loop:

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var topForThisOne = $(this).offset().top;
});
```

Comment: @vijith - I wouldn't use a derived value like that in your program logic. Instead, drive the animation by the program logic. But in any case, you know when the top value reaches 400: 7,000ms after you start the animation.

Comment: This is part of a small typing game which I am working on right now, Words will be randomly generated and move down continuously, when the generated word matches with the word on the text box the class box will hide, the remaining words will go down and fadeout, I wants to retrieve the top value when the animation is finished and use that value to reduce the game life of the player, basically when the randomly generated word reaches on the bottom the player should loose a life.